# Sum of finite series $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}\frac{(-z)^x}{x!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the finite series:
 $$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}\frac{(-z)^x}{x!}$$
?

When $n \to \infty$, then it [obviously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Exponential_function) equals $e^{-z}$.
But what is its equivalent expression when, for example, $n=10$ ?

Comment: well if $n=10$ it is $\sum_{x=0}^{10} \frac{(-z)^x}{x!}$, or if you like better $\exp(-z)-\sum_{x=11}^\infty \frac{(-z)^x}{x!}$, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Looking for something like $e^{a \cdot z}$. The expression shouldn't include a sum...

Comment: $\exp(a\cdot z)$ cant work because for $z=1$ you have for $n=1$ the sum to be 0, but the exponential function doesn't have a zero

Comment: With a finite number of terms it's just a polynomial, so "something like $e^{az}$" is not a very realistic expectation...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: That's why I wrote "something like...", 'cause I don't know the expression which I'm looking for...

Comment: @Dor: what you want is called 'closed form', which, I think, doesn't exist for finite $n$ of this series. You can, nevertheless, get something else: approximations, assymptotics, $\Gamma$ function expressions, etc

Comment: @Alex That seems exactly what I need

Comment: @Dor well I am pretty sure something like that doesn't exist, as by Hermite-Lindemann the exponential of some algebraic non zero number is transcendent, so your closed form does need some functions which have implict some non finite sums or something else which is far more complicated than a finite sum. and writing $\exp(x)$ is only a short form for writing the series, it isn't an easier term after all

Comment: isn't $_1F_1(-n,-n,-z)$ what you are after?

Comment: @Ewcz in which world is an hypergeometric function easier than a finite sum?

Comment: sure, it doesn't change almost anything, my idea was that if one would need to calculate the sum numerically that it could be an option to use a library which implements hypergeometric functions, e.g., GSL, instead of coding the sum oneself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can offer is an expression in terms of the incomplete Gamma-function:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-z)^k}{k!} = \frac{e^{-z}}{n!}\Gamma(n+1,-z), $$
where
$$ \Gamma(a,w) = \int_{w}^{\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t} \, dt. $$
It is easy to show by integrating by parts that this satisfies
$$ \Gamma(a,w) = -w^{a-1}e^{-w}+(a-1)\Gamma(a-1,w), $$
so it should be fairly clear what's going on there. You then have [extensive results](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8) on many properties of this function to draw on.

(And yes, this is not far from the integral form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem. That's to be expected, really: you're very unlikely to be able to find a closed-form representation for the partial sums of any particular function.)

Answer (score 0):

An approximation of the sum which does not include a sum could be the first term, $\frac{(-z)^0}{0!} = 1$. Furthermore, this approximation can be expressed as $e^0$.

Comment: Not necesserily: it can be some assymptotic expression